# Game which allows to test AI algorithms

Tags: java, c++, python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for a game which will allow me to test various artificial intelligence, reinforcement learning and machine learning algorithms. It would be great, if there will be good documentation or even helpful framework for writing AI. I know about TORCS, but do you know other games? It doesn't matter in which language it is written. It can be any arcade game, simulator, FPS, etc.

Comment: You need to clarify what games you are talking about. Most "Video" games aren't ripe for machine learning. If you want to do machine learning you need data not a framework or programatic access to the game.

Comment: [marioai](https://code.google.com/p/marioai/)

Comment: [Robocode](http://robocode.sourceforge.net/) is a "game" where you program the AI for a tank. I know that it has an interface for at least Java and C#

Answer (score 2):

Quake 3 is an ideal candidate for bot design.

- open source code base.
- Realistic scenario (compared to robocode which is a toy domain).
- existing bots and I believe the first bots used in Quake 3 where the output of a Ph.D.
- lots of documentation.

Comment: Do you know any good source of information about writing/designing a bot in Q3?

Comment: google is your friend. [Here](http://aigamedev.com/open/article/quake3-engine/) you go though.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [ISBoxer](http://isboxer.com), a platform for multiboxing games. It might seem like that suggestion is offtopic, but this is not the case. The platform has a scripting engine inbuilt and people have create injection based API's for certain games (Everquest, Eve online, world of warcraft, and more that I don't know of).

This might not be what you are looking for, since the bots in this context are written as state machines. But it is something worth considering.